# Coin Class HW assignment

Tags: class, debugging, random, syntax, coin-flipping

So I am doing a Coin Flip Class program for class, and this code straight from the book is giving me errors in Pycharm and VSC. I have reread this 10 times and can not find the error to get the program to run. Trying to figure out if I am missing something, or the example source code is off.

```
import random


# The Coin Class simulates a coin that can be flipped

class coin:
    def __init__(self):
        side.up = 'Heads'

    # Side up data attribute w/ heads

    # The Toss generates a random number in
    # the range of 0 - 1. If the number is 0, then side up is heads, otherwise side up is tails

    def toss(self):

        if random.randint(0, 1) == 0:
            self.sideup = 'Heads'
        else:
            self.sideup = 'Tails'

    # The get_sideup method returns the value referenced by sideup

    def get_sideup(self):
        return self.sideup

    # The main function


def main():
    # create an object from the coin class
    my_coin = coin()

    # Display that side facing up
    print('This side is up:', my_coin.get_sideup())

    # Toss Coin
    print('I am tossing the coin . . .')
    my_coin.toss()

    # Display the side of the coin that is facing up
    print('This side is up:', my_coin.get_sideup())

    # Call the main function
main()
``
```

Comment: You should have gotten an error message along the lines of `NameError: name 'side' is not defined.`  Change `side.up = 'Heads'` to `self.sideup = 'Heads'` in `__init__`.

Comment: Note that the error messages generated are an integral part of the problem description, and should be included in your question. Even better, it's an essential skill to learn how to read them so you can debug your programs independently.

Answer (score 0):

You have a variable that is equal to nothing, self, and you are attempting to access an attribute of it called "up"

```py
    def __init__(self):
        side.up = 'Heads'
```